# Simple form issue with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I've been trying recently to show a list of the fields modified with success on submitting a form. The only problem is that my form (I use simple form) doesn't show the errors when there are some and the form can't be submitted.

Here's my code simplified :

```
def update
  @wizard.assign_attributes(params[:wizard])
  # Get changed attributes

  if @wizard.save
    # Set the success flash with fields modified
    redirect_to @wizard
  else
    @title = "Edition du profil"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

The view :

```
<%= simple_form_for @wizard do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :story %>

    <%= f.submit "Modifier", :class => "btn success small" %>
<% end %>
```

The model :

```
class Wizard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  attr_accessible :email, :story, :password, :password_confirmation, :password_digest

  serialize :ranks, Array

  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :story
  validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation, :unless => Proc.new { |w| w.password_digest.present? }

  # Other validations here

  has_one :subject, :foreign_key => "teacher_id"

  ROLES = %w[teacher]

  scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_bitmask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0"} }

  # Other functions here
end
```

Has anyone an idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You should post your view code as well.

Comment: Where did you get the `assign_attributes` (it's rails 3.1 specific, `update_attributes` is more commonly used in the previous versions)? Are you doing mass-assignment on the wizard?

Comment: I use Rails 3.1. In fact, all my models are protected against mass-assigment because I've overwritten ActiveRecord::Base. Here I can't do it with update_attributes because I have to assign them first without saving to get the changes done in the model.

Comment: It's justified then :-) But your problem could come from there (nothing looks wrong in the code you've posted so far).

Comment: Yeah the mistake is probably here because I use update_attributes in all my other controllers and it works well.

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful but that's done ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has probably something to do with how you overwrote AR. I remember some plugin getting in trouble with assign_attributes. Meanwhile you can try :

```
@wizard.assign_attributes(params[:wizard], :without_protection => true)
```

If that works it will at least narrow down the problem to mass assignment.

Comment: In fact, I solved the problem wrapping the files in the form in a fieldset_tag. I just can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

you perhaps missing this part in edit/new view.Where `@wizard` is your model_name.
Write this piece of code in the form tag.

```
<% if @wizard.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@wizard.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @wizard.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: In fact, in my other forms, simple form does it automatically with my own CSS styling and so on. What I'm looking for is the reason why it's not the case here.